# Compare files in two folder

Tags: windows, directory

How can compare files of two different type that contain the contain same name in two different folders.

Lets have i have a file called file1.mkv in folder 1 and and in folder 2  file.1.torrent , as you can see they are different types, but have same name essentially.

How can i list or match all the files that have at least one equal word in their name ?

Im on windows 7 so im just hoping for the best , no Linux here unfortunately.

Comment: You should post this either at [SU] or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Download beyond compare.
This is what you need

http://download.cnet.com/Beyond-Compare/3000-2242_4-10015731.html